# How do I move an image in Cloudinary?

Tags: javascript, fetch, cloudinary

Using a fetch method, I am trying to move an uploaded image to another folder inside the same Cloudinary account.

I'm trying to move an image using this piece of code:

```
const CLOUDINARY_URL = `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/CLOUD_NAME/image/rename`;
const api_key = ******;
const image = {
    ...image,
    url: 'the full url of the image',
    public_id: 'the public id of the image'
}
const to_public_id = 'the new folder/name to where it should move to'

let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("api_key", api_key);
formData.append("from_public_id", image.public_id);
formData.append("to_public_id", to_public_id);
formData.append("signature", "NOT SURE WHAT TO PUT HERE");

const res = await fetch(CLOUDINARY_URL, {
  method: "POST",
  body: formData,
});
```

somehow, this results in a CORS error, showing this error:

```
{"error":{"message":"Unknown API key "}}
```

What am I doing wrong?

And how do I obtain/set the signature?

Answer (score 0):

Using the REST API's require a signature to make sure the call is valid request.

For your case, you need to create a manual signature. You can follow Cloudinary's documentation here:

https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#generating_authentication_signatures

Hope this helps,
John